# How do I only allow the user to enter sensible height and weight values in Edit Text? Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, validation, android-layout

I'm making a super simple BMI calculator app using Java in android studio but I'd like to make it so that the user is only able to enter sensible values for their height and weight. I was thinking something around 50cm-220cm for height and 3kg-150kg for weight. As it stands, they can enter any number and come out with absurdly high or low BMI values. What is a super simple way of solving this?

I really appreciate any help :)

I've included my main activity code down below, as well as a link to my android studio project so far.

```
package com.example.bmicalc2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telecom.TelecomManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.style.LineHeightSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText Weight, Height;
private TextView ResultText;
String calculation, BMIResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Weight = findViewById(R.id.Weight);
    Height = findViewById(R.id.Height);
    ResultText = findViewById(R.id.result);
}

public void calculateBMI(View view) {
    final String Wt = Weight.getText().toString();
    String Ht = Height.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Wt)){
        Weight.setError("Please enter your weight!");
        Weight.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Ht)){
        Height.setError("Please enter your height!");
        Height.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    else {

    float weightValue = Float.parseFloat(Wt);
    float heightValue = Float.parseFloat(Ht) / 100;

    float bmi = weightValue / (heightValue * heightValue);

    if (bmi < 18.5){
        BMIResult = "You are in the underweight BMI range!";
    }
    else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
        BMIResult = "You are in the healthy weight BMI range!";
    }
    else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi >= 29.9){
        BMIResult = "You are in the overweight BMI range!";
    }
    else if (bmi > 30){
        BMIResult = "You are in the obese BMI range!";
    }

    calculation = "Result: " + String.format("%.2f", bmi) + "\n" + BMIResult;
    ResultText.setText(calculation);
        }
    }
}
```

Google Drive Link to my project thus far: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yMwnf7aF2D_gQ47v3BonBRPh9xdFv0x9?usp=sharing

Comment: you can simply have validations and check. For eg :- check if your `EditText Weight` value is in range of `3 to 150`. I suppose you have a inout type to number in your xml so you can easily convert your `EditText` value in `Int` and have a simple comparison in that.

Comment: Hi Mohammed! Yes I do have the Input Type as number at the moment in my XML file. So how would I go about changing this and setting a range? Thanks!

Comment: no need to set range in xml you can just check the range in your java code while calculating your BMI. If your height or weight is not in the given range then you can simply return from that point without doing further implementation. For eg :- `if (Ht.toInt() in 3..150)` then do your further calculations else `return` with some error message

Comment: Ok Mohammed but I don't understand how I actually do that if you get what I mean?

Comment: I have added an answer please have a look once and let me know if you are stuck anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your `calculate BMI`

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Wt)){
    Weight.setError("Please enter your weight!");
    Weight.requestFocus();
    return;
}
else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Ht)){
    Height.setError("Please enter your height!");
    Height.requestFocus();
    return;
}
else if (Integer.parseInt(Wt) < 3 || Integer.parseInt(Wt) > 150) {
    Weight.setError("Please enter your weight in range of 3 to 150!");
    Weight.requestFocus();
    return;
} else if (Integer.parseInt(Ht) < 50 || Integer.parseInt(Ht) > 220) 
    Height.setError("Please enter your height in range of 50 to 220!");
    Height.requestFocus();
    return;
} else {
    double weightValue = Double.parseFloat(Wt);
    double heightValue = Double.parseFloat(Ht) / 100;
    // Your further Implementation
```

Here I have only added only two more conditions `if (Integer.parseInt(Wt) < 3 || Integer.parseInt(Wt) > 150)`  and similarly for height. What I am doing is you have already check if `Wt` or `Ht` is not `empty` so I have directly fetched it's Integer value using `Integer.parseInt(Ht)` similarly for `weight` (you can do this in `try` `catch` block if you want) and then I simply checked if the `Integer.parseInt(Ht)` similarly for `weight` is in the required range or not and throw error accordingly.

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for! It works perfectly and is really concise and simple! Thank you so much, Mohammed, you're my saviour! :D

Comment: Glad to help bro.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about logic now. Now i will provide you example with proper height in centimeter and calculate

Formula of

> BMI =  Mass / (Height * Height) //I don't know how to put square on top so i just multiplied it twice. Height should be in meters.

Make class for MinandMax Range (you can find this code on google) :

```
package com.test;

import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private double min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(double min, double max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Double.parseDouble(min);
        this.max = Double.parseDouble(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Then assign to your editttext :

```
Weight = findViewById(R.id.Weight);
Height = findViewById(R.id.Height);
Weight.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("3", "150")});
Height.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("50", "220")});
```

Now just check if it's empty or no onclick :

```
public void calculateBMI(View view) {
    final String Wt = Weight.getText().toString();
    String Ht = Height.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Wt)){
        Weight.setError("Please enter your weight!");
        Weight.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Ht)){
        Height.setError("Please enter your height!");
        Height.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    else {
        double weightValue = Double.parseFloat(Wt);
        double heightValue = Double.parseFloat(Ht) / 100;

        double bmi = (double) weightValue / (heightValue * heightValue);

        if (bmi < 18.5){
            BMIResult = "You are in the underweight BMI range!";
        }
        else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
            BMIResult = "You are in the healthy weight BMI range!";
        }
        else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi >= 29.9){
            BMIResult = "You are in the overweight BMI range!";
        }
        else if (bmi > 30){
            BMIResult = "You are in the obese BMI range!";
        }

            calculation = "Result: " + String.format("%.2f", bmi) + "\n" + BMIResult;
            ResultText.setText(calculation);
        }
    }
}
```

Now try the code

Comment: Hey Ashish! Thank you for your response! I did see the article on this actually and I've tried this code but there are major issues. This stops the user from entering any number outside the min and max range. For example for the users weight, they are unable to enter the numbers 1, 2 and 3. And with Height they can't enter any numbers at all for some reason. I looked at the solution to this and its far more complicated. Surely there's an easier way for me to throw an error to the user if they enter values outside of a range?

Comment: @Super if you read op question then it asks for range from 3 to 150 and 50 - 220